# How to find the size of the largest doc lib

Tags: 2010

Is there a way to find the document library of which total size (the sum of sizes of its contained documents) is the largest in the farm.

I checked Web Analytics --> Inventory --> Storage Usage

But it didn't provide what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you have access to powershell then use this

```
#Get the Site collection
$Site = Get-SPsite "http://sharepoint.crescent.com"

#Returns a DataTable similar to "Storage Management Page" in Site settings
$DataTable = $Site.StorageManagementInformation(2,0x11,0,10)

$DataTable | Select Title, ItemCount, Size, Directory | Format-Table
```

[Get SharePoint Library Size with PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/01/get-sharepoint-library-size-powershell.html)